# In SiwftUI, is it possible to show/hide/change the image for a parent menu based on whether its children are visible/hidden?

Tags: swift, swiftui, contextmenu

### TL;DR

I have an 'Icon Style' parent menu that lists all available styles as submenu items. Additionally, it shows the currently-selected style as its icon (to the right of the text.)

I am hoping to control the visibility of that icon depending on if the submenu is open/expanded or closed/collapsed.

### The Details

This is best illustrated with images.

As you can see in this first one, 'Icon Style' is a submenu that has an icon showing you the current selection. ***I want to see this icon, but only when the menu is closed!***

[image]

However, when you open the menu, you now have the image in two places... up top by 'Icon Style' and as an option below.  Additionally, you have the checkmark on the left.  Not only is this approach redundant, but it also makes the screen look more 'busy' than it needs to.

[image]

What I'd like to figure out how to do is if the submenu is closed, show the icon (like in the first image above.) If however it's open, hide the icon next to the submenu's top item, like this...

[image]

From other questions I've found around the net, including here, they suggest this, but this does not print in the log window for me. And even if it did, I'm not quite sure how to get the state of the menu from this.  I mean a person could tap to open it, then tap again to collapse it, and trying to manually 'sync' seems like code-smell to me.

```swift
Menu {
    Button("Sort Order", action: {})
    Button("Check All", action: {})
    Button("Uncheck All", action: {})
    Menu {
        Button("Style A", action: {})
        Button("Style B", action: {})
        ....
    } label: {
        Label("Icon Style", systemImage: "checkmark.square.fill")
    }
    .contentShape(Rectangle())
    .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded {
        print(">> tapped")
    })
    Button("Save as PDF", action: {})
}
```

So... is this possible?  Spent about 2 hrs looking so far with no luck.

### Bonus Question

In Apple's 'Reminders' app, for the 'Sort By' heading, they have the main text, then subtext underneath it showing you the current sort value.  However, I don't see any API that lets you add custom views for the 'text' portion.  Again, searching around here people talk about embedding UIKit views for that, but that just seems like overkill to me.  But maybe that's the solution.

Comment: Can you try replacing label with `Text("Icon Style")` instead. See if that helps. Also there is a typo in your question I think it needs to be `Menu("some text") {`

Comment: Yes, I can do that, but then I lose the icon in the 'collapsed' state.  I want to see the icon when it's collapsed, then fade/hide it when the submenu opens. If the submenu is again closed, I want to fade it back in again.  Make sense?  I'll add this for clarity above.

Comment: Not sure this helps, only thing I can think of is you could choose an icon distinctly different from the submenu. At least something that is not filled. Also look for apps that use this design and see how they have handled it.

Comment: Why not just use an `@State` boolean value, which tracks whether the list has been tapped? If it has, just change your `systemImage: ` to `""`

Comment: @Stoic, do you have an example for tracking taps on a parent menu with children under them?  Not sure how you get that info. (I'm new to SwiftUI and am only aware of the `defaultAction` for menus, which doesn't apply here.  If you  put it in an answer, if it works, I'll accept it.